# How to animate a array of dynamic images using xcode?

Tags: arrays, xcode, animation, uiimageview

I have a list of URL. Each url has an image of specific size.

What I want to do is, I want to parse those URLs and extract image. And then give those images to UIImageView as an array of images which will animate them.

Take it as you want to display your photos stored somewhere online to your ipad application with different animation.

How can i achieve the transition from URL to the UIImageView?

I am using Xcode 4 for iPad application.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? And what've you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think first of all you have to fetch images from the URL's you have and put them inito an array and then set this array as `animationImages` of a `UIImageView`. Then set `animationDuration` ,`animationRepeatCount` of `UIImageView` and call `startAnimating` on this `UIImageView`.

To parse images from URL use-

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentOfURL:[NSURL urlWithString:@"http://........"]];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

then add this image to a array.

UIImageView animation -

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake()];

imgView.animationImages  = array;
imgView.animationDuration = 2.0;
imgView.animationRepeatCount = 0;

[imgView startAnimating];
```

for more info about UIImageView animation follow-

http://appsamuck.com/day2.html